# mPDF to render image as flipped and hidden within container

Tags: image, mpdf

I am using mPDF(v7.0) to create a PDF from my HTML. I want to create a PDF that contains an image, within a div (.container-sizing). I have to be able to have the ability to position the image within .container-sizing using CSS and zoom and flip the image.

I have tried the below:

CSS

```
.container-sizing {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width:600px;
    height:430px;
 }
 .img {
     max-height: 100%;
     position: absolute;
     top: -100px;
     left: -100px;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     margin: auto;
     transform:scale(1, -1);
 }
```

HTML

```
<div class='container-sizing'> 
    <img src='images/my-image.jpg' alt='' class='img'/>
</div>
```

This doesn't work as it ignores `overflow:hidden` on the containing div - which is pretty essential when positioning the image. Instead, I tried styling the image as a background image, which works great but then I have run into problems with `transform: scale(1, -1)`. Despite mPDF's documentation saying that this is supported, it doesn't seem to work when applied to a background image.

CSS:

```
.container-sizing {
    width:600px;
    height:430px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.img {
    background-image: url('images/my-image.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    width:600px;
    height:430px;
    transform:scale(1, -1) ;                             
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class='container-sizing'>
    <div class='img'></div>
</div>
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I can get this working to produce a pdf that shows the image how it is declared in the css?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After spending ages trying to figure this out, I ended up dropping mPDF and using domPDF instead as this supports the `overflow: hidden` property I needed. Just posting in case anyone else runs into a similar issue!